# Getting 403 (forbidden) error on VirusTotal API

Tags: python, api

I was trying to use the VirusTotal API to scan URLs from a file following [this](https://developers.virustotal.com/v2.0/reference/url-scan) example
When running the program it returns me in the file a <Response [403]> (forbidden).
Basically the only thing I found is that I could have made an error when writting my API key but I checked and double checked and it seems correct.

Do you know where this could come from ?

```
import requests
minute = 60
from time import sleep
file = open("url.txt","r") #url file contains all URLs
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
for line in lines:
    url = "http://" + line[:-3] #Added that because my URLs didn't have http:// at the beggining and contained "Â" at the end because of encoding
    params = {'apikey': 'my_API_key', 'url':url} # My API key is written inside the '' as such '123456'
    response = requests.post(url, data=params)
    responsesFile = open("Responses.txt","w")
    responsesFile.write(str(response))
    sleep(5*minute)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Edit : I don't know exactly why the above code didn't work but using the API V3, I found a code that is working, here is the base

```
import requests
import json
import base64

headers = {'x-apikey': 'VT_API_KEY'}
resource = "https://www.lacoste.com"
endpoint = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls"
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers , data = 
{'url':resource})

print(response.json())

analysis_id = response.json()['data']['id']
analysis_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/analyses/" + analysis_id
response = requests.get(analysis_url, headers=headers)
response_json = response.json()
print(response_json)
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Can you debug or give some examples what `url` looks like ?

Comment: Url looked like this : "google.com" in my textfile. When running the code it looked looked like this "google.comÂ". So I had to add "http://" at the beginning and remove the "Â" when testing, I had to remove 3 characters for it to work properly

Comment: Most likely it seem to be an encoding problem, add a `print(url)` to verify encoding issues, if it is wrong you need to change encoding in open() call, or write file with different encoding.

Answer (score 0):

you'll notice, in the example that works, you're including the api key in the headers. In your previous attempt you were putting the api key in the post data. Authentication data is almost always included in the headers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It sures makes more sense
What is strange is that including the api-key in the post data was done in the example on VirusTotal website

Comment: maybe they accepted both at one time, but accepting it in the POST data leads to inconsistent behaviour when you want to GET, you obviously can't send POST data with a GET request, you would have to include it in the url parameters, but url params are often exposed in logs and are less secure. So they probably stopped accepting it in the POST to avoid newbies exposing their API keys in the GET and forgot to update their examples. OAuth uses headers, if it's good enough for OAuth, it's good enough for yo' auth.